# calculate the real distance between two points in an image with python

Tags: python, image-processing, exif

In connection with a business project, I need to find the real distance between two points in the images received from the mobile phone. Due to the lack of information such as the physical size of image sensors in smartphone cameras in the EXIF file, by estimating the distance and forcing the user to place an object with a certain height and width in the image, I was able to estimate the size of the image sensor but with some error. ‌‌But these errors can be avoided and will not be very problematic. To do this, I followed the tips in this post.

https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12434/how-do-i-calculate-the-distance-of-an-object-in-a-photo/12437#12437

Now I am looking to find the distance between two points in the image. According to this link,

[calculate the real distance between to point using image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22696983/calculate-the-real-distance-between-to-point-using-image)

the distance between the two desired points can be obtained, but I did not understand how the column and row in this formula are obtained.

I would be very grateful if I could get help. If I went the wrong way, thank you for explaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link you shared, the points u,v are image centers, which are found using the sensor/digitizer row and column and the width and height of the image.

This paper explains image centers well:
https://www.ri.cmu.edu/pub_files/pub4/willson_reg_1994_3/willson_reg_1994_3.pdf

But nonetheless, the row and column values are part of the actual camera itself, not relative to the image necessarily.

Beyond that point, everything else is found using those two values along with the z-axis value and focal length, which is then plugged into the Euclidian distance formula.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So you mean that without u and v and even the size of the image sensor, just by having the distance in millimeters for each pixel and having the focal length, we can get the distance between every two points in the image in millimeters?

Comment: Based on what I read in the stack post you sent, it seems that you need both u and v alongside the focal length and image width and height to calculate the x and y coordinates in the 3D space, then beyond that point, it's just Euclidian distance.

Comment: Yes. That's right. I read the article you mentioned. Unfortunately, I still do not understand what rows and columns mean in calculating u and v. Can you explain these two concepts a bit?

Comment: I'm not sure what you'd like me to explain, but here's a few great resources I was able to find:
https://www.ri.cmu.edu/pub_files/pub2/willson_reg_1993_1/willson_reg_1993_1.pdf this paper explains the calculation of image centers really well,
and these two explain how the information is used programmatically relative to the other sensor features:
https://www.edmundoptics.com/knowledge-center/application-notes/imaging/understanding-camera-sensors-for-machine-vision-applications/
https://www.flir.com/support-center/iis/machine-vision/application-note/geometric-vision-using-ladybug-cameras/

Comment: Thank you very much. I think based on this [link](https://www.flir.com/support-center/iis/machine-vision/application-note/geometric-vision-using-ladybug-cameras/) I could understand. My question was what the terms "width" and "column" mean in the equation "u = column - width / 2". Based on the link you sent, I realized that "width" is actually the width of the image and "column" means the position of the desired pixel in the vector y. Thank you very much again.